# Jackson @JsonIgnore changed semantics?

Tags: java, json, jackson

We just upgraded some maven dependencies, that triggered an update of Jackson from 1.7.x to 1.9.x

We use to annotate @JsonIgnore on setter methods, on methods not supposed to be set from client side. for example: the owner of an object (with should be set from the authentication principal), etc.

It seems to us that the semanthincs of this annotation have changed, is that possible? now the field is been jsonignored in all case, and not only when being set.

is that the case? is there an alternative way in 1.9 to implement ignore SET only?

thanks!
r.

Comment: Are you adding the @JsonProperty annotation on the field or the getter?

Comment: I am adding it on the Setter. Which preventing it to be set during de-Serialization in 1.7.x

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I think I found and explicit mention to this issue in the javadoc. (jackson documentation is not easy to go through).

> In addition, starting with Jackson 1.9, if this is the only annotation associated with a property, it will also cause cause the whole property to be ignored: that is, if setter has this annotation and getter has no annotations, getter is also effectively ignored. It is still possible for different accessors to use different annotations; so if only "getter" is to be ignored, other accessors (setter or field) would need explicit annotation to prevent ignoral (usually JsonProperty).

Comment: Correct. This was the big change in 1.9 (which in hindsight maybe should have waited until 2.0). To achieve what you want ("split accessors"), you do need to add explicit `@JsonProperty` on getter -- default is to assume that if just one relevant annotation is found, it applies to all parts of a "full" property.